# Create a cpShape from a CGRect in cocos2d and chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, shapes, chipmunk, cgrect

I can't figure out how to create a cpShape that will fit a CGRect. Here is what I tried so far, without any success :

```
    CGPoint p1 = rect.origin;
    CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint p3 = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGPoint p4 = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);

    int num = 4;
    CGPoint verts[] = {p2, p1, p3, p4};
    shape = cpPolyShapeNew(body, num, verts, cpvzero);
```

I don't understand why this doesn't fit perfectly my CGRect ?

Comment: is the question still open, or did your edit solve the question? If so, you should post the solution as an answer, not as an edit within your question.

Comment: To answer I had to wait 8hours. That's why I edited

Comment: ah, I didn't know that. I moved the answer part to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Answered on behalf of [user251552](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251552/user251552)

Ok I figured this out:

```
//Converting points in chipmunk coordinates
    CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(-rect.size.width/2, -rect.size.height/2);
    CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(-rect.size.width/2, +rect.size.height/2);
    CGPoint p3 = CGPointMake(+rect.size.width/2, +rect.size.height/2);
    CGPoint p4 = CGPointMake(+rect.size.width/2, -rect.size.height/2);

    int num = 4;
    CGPoint verts[] = {p1, p2, p3, p4};

    shape = cpPolyShapeNew(body, num, verts, cpvzero);
```